# Checking for anagram strings in linear time

Tags: python, algorithm

So given an input of two strings I have the following linear time solution to check if one string is an anagram of the other. I wanted a more concise and pythonic linear time solution to this.

```
def perm_check(str1,str2):

    if len(str1)!=len(str2):
        return False

    d1,d2={},{}

    for i in range(len(str1)):

        l1=str1[i]
        l2=str2[i]

        if l1 in d1:
            d1[l1]+=1
        else:
            d1[l1]=1


        if l2 in d2:
            d2[l2]+=1
        else:
            d2[l2]=1


    for letter in d1:

        if letter not in d2:
            return False

        if d1[letter] != d2[letter]:

            return False        

    return True


print(perm_check("stab","bats"))
```

How can I optimize this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use python [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) class to do this. Basically, in anagrams, the count of each character has to be same between the two strings, so all you need is a character count of each character in both the strings, and compare them. The `Counter` class will create the dictionaries for you, which you can directly compare.

```
from collections import Counter

def is_anagram(string1, string2):
    return Counter(string1) == Counter(string2)
```

Result:

```
>>> is_anagram("helper", "perhel")
True
>>> is_anagram("helper", "perhe")
False
>>> is_anagram("helper", "perhes")
False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either counter as mentioned in the other answer, or a dictionary to go through the elements and count the frequency of every character.

You can use `zip` to traverse two lists, by getting elements in the same position (just to accelerate things as they have the same length ). If the key exist, we add one. If it doesn't exist, we add the key to the dictionary, with a value `1`

```
def perm_check(str1,str2):
    if len(str1)!=len(str2):
        return False

    d1,d2={},{}

    for x,y in zip(list(str1),list(str2)):
        if x not in d1.keys():
            d1[x]=1
        else:
            d1[x]+=1

        if y not in d2.keys():
            d2[y]=1
        else:
            d2[y]+=1


    return d1==d2

print perm_check("dad","add") #True

print perm_check("dad","adb") #False
```

Answer (score 1):

using sorted:

```
>>> def anagram(str1,str2):
...     return sorted(str1) == sorted(str2)
... 
>>> anagram('hello','ellho')
True
>>> anagram('abcd','cabd')
True
>>> anagram('hello','hellohe')
False
```

Comment: sorting the string is nlogn at best, so worse than linear time

Comment: Even though @sarathjoseph  is right, +1 none the less. For smaller strings, sorted will give better performance becuase there will be no overhead of creating a dictionary like in Counter.

Comment: Example: `string1, string2 = "herlper", "herrlpe"`. Now when using sorted, `%timeit sorted(string1) == sorted(string2)` gives
`1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.39 µs per loop`, while on using Counter,
`%timeit Counter(string1) == Counter(string2)` gives `100000 loops, best of 3: 8.48 µs per loop`

Comment: @sarathjoseph Sorting a string over a finite alphabet is O(n), not O(n log n).

Answer (score 0):

```
potential = ["ice", "cei", "cheese", "pool", "loop", "oolp", "eseehc"]
sets = []
setCount = {}
results = []
for anagram in potential:
    sets.append((set(anagram), anagram))
for x in sets:
    if not ''.join(list(x[0])) in setCount:
        setCount[''.join(list(x[0]))] = [x[1]]
    elif len(setCount[''.join(list(x[0]))][0]) == len(x[1]):
        setCount[''.join(list(x[0]))].append(x[1])
        results += setCount[''.join(list(x[0]))]
print(list(set(results)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest algorithm is possibly via the prime numbers. Start with a mapping of each letter to a unique prime number. The first 26 prime numbers take you till 101. For both the words, take the product of the numbers corresponding to the letters. Since the prime decomposition of a composite number is unique, comparing the products of the two words will verify if they are anagrams.